# Rails: Assign a constant which can be used in all controllers

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The class needs to use `EWKB` in various controller actions, thus defined:

```
def EWKB
  EWKB = RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
end

def self.containing_latlon(lat, lon, polygon)
  ewkb = EWKB.generate(FACTORY.point(lon, lat).projection)
  where("ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\\\x#{ewkb}'))")
end
```

The above definition, returns `syntax error: dynamic constant assignment`.
In its stead, I defined

```
def EWKB
  RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
end
```

and the error disappears.  As the second method needs to invoke it, I am not certain how/if ruby will handle this constructor as

```
def self.containing_latlon(lat, lon, polygon)
  EWKB = RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
  ewkb = EWKB.generate(FACTORY.point(lon, lat).projection)
  where("ST_Intersects(polygon, ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\\\x#{ewkb}'))")
end
```

leads to the same spot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow naming conventions. Constants are `CamelCase`, method and variable names are `snake_case`. Interpreter are going mad trying to understand what do you want. Just define a constant in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
EWKB = RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
```

And then use it.

Another way is to define a method:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def self.ewkb
    # caching the assignment
    @ewkb ||= RGeo::WKRep::WKBGenerator.new(:type_format => :ewkb, :emit_ewkb_srid => true, :hex_format => true)
  end
end

class MyController < ApplicationController
   def my_action
     ApplicationController.ewkb
   end
end
```

Use what you like, just don't mix them.